# Spring security logging form inside another page

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, authentication, logging

I have found really lot of examples, how to make spring security custom logging page and how to configure redirect to it if authorization is needed.

But I can’t find how to make logging form inside another page, for example inside home.html.
I can imagine I will use Thymeleaf fragments to insert custom logging page inside home page. But I don’t know how to connect it to authentication process (also without any redirection to home.html)

Thank you for replies

Petr

Comment: Just add it... Let it post to the login url (default `j_spring_security_login` and pass a `j_username` and `j_password` property). It is just a form.. Nothing more...

Comment: Thank you, your post has explained whats going on. I would only add for those who will read this question: if you are using JavaConfig, instead `j_spring_security_login` use `login`, instead `j_username` `username` and instead `j_password` `password`